# appcelerator workaround for ti.include not working

Tags: include, filesystems, titanium, appcelerator

Hi I have tried the workaround suggested by the appcelerator team (for dealing with the deprecation of ti.include in version 6.0.0)

```
function include(file) {
    return eval(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, file).read().text); 
}
```

And I get an error, probably the system can't read the file. the error is:

> [ERROR] :  TiBlob: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   Resources/underscore-min.js

I have managed to list the directory files through .getDirectoryListing() and couldn't find the file, actually I couldn't find any .js file there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Don't try to use the workaround but migrate your apps to the correct `require` functionality. The `Ti.include()` method has been deprecated since 3.3.0 (!) and has been removed in 6.0.0 (3 major versions later). All current and future apps use this behavior for scalable high-performance apps and so should you.

For your use-case, this is how you would use your library nowadays:

```
var _ = require('underscore-min')
```

It expects your file to be placed in `<project-root>/Resources/underscore-min.js` (Classic projects) or `<project-root>/app/lib/underscore-min.js` (Alloy projects).

Read more about `require` and how to use it [here](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Global-method-require) and [here](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium).

Code strong!

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborated answer that worked great!

Comment: Hi Guys, this is not working for me, is there something else i should do ? https://www.evernote.com/l/ACRAvzocIJpNm4oXmTU0FdC5gA289bm6yVk

Comment: Please read the links I attached. You have to export variables and method like this: exports.myMethod = function() { ... };